# Android: Overlap children elements of ViewGroup without adding parent framelayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I need a framelayout to overlay another framelayout. If a ViewGroup element has two child elements like this (**it needs exactly two children so I cannot add another parent framelayout**):

```
<CustomViewGroup> #needs exactly two children


<FrameLayout></FrameLayout> #first child

<FrameLayout></FrameLayout> #second child, should overlay over the first


</CustomViewGroup>
```

How can I still overlay the second framelayout over the first?
In this current configuration the first child gets resized when I make the second child visible.

How it should be:
- Two framelayouts in customviewgroup
- The framelayout should overlay the first framelayout (its a custom drawer from the botton

What happens at the moment:
- The second framelayout doesn't overlay the first but positions below it

Comment: and why do you need those two framelayouts?

Comment: The CustomViewGroup is built on the assumption that there are exactly two elements so I cannot change this easily. Or is there a way to make a framelayout that is "invisible" to the XML hierarchy?

Comment: ok, so whats your exact problem since i dont get it... every framelayout is invisible, so?

Comment: please see my edit above

Comment: your custom ViewGroup has two children: two FrameLayouts, you can posirion them in onLayout method by calling layout(l, t, r, b)